# Not able to get the employee image from workday using Get_Employee_Image

Tags: python, workday-api

https://community.workday.com/sites/default/files/file-hosting/productionapi/Human_Resources/v30.1/Get_Employee_Image.html

I am trying to fetch the Employee Image from Workday using above method.

```
result = client.service.Get_Employee_Image({"Integration_ID_Reference": {"ID":  {"System_ID":"XXXXX"} }})
```

I am getting below error

```
zeep.exceptions.Fault: Validation error occurred. Employee Reference Integration ID does not exist!
```

I am able to fetch the data from Soap Api.

[image]

Comment: It doesn't look like you are passing the "WD-EMPLID" in your code, so it doesn't know to apply the Employee ID to the correct Integration ID Reference.

Answer (score 1):

```
result = client.service.Get_Employee_Image(Employee_Reference=
                                                {"Integration_ID_Reference":
                                                    {"ID":{ "System_ID" :"your_system_id",
                                                           "_value_1":11111<empid>}}})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

We could not get the client service to pass multiple variables as used in the SOAP interface.  What solved our problem is writing the HML from SOAP and passing it directly  to the resource service.

```
def __get_Employee_image(employee):
    return '''<wd:Employee_Image_Get xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc" 
wd:version="v36.1">
        <wd:Employee_Reference>
            <wd:Integration_ID_Reference>
                <wd:ID wd:System_ID="WD-EMPLID">{e}</wd:ID>
            </wd:Integration_ID_Reference>
        </wd:Employee_Reference>
    </wd:Employee_Image_Get>'''.format(e=employee)
```